# Is there a way to get the captions in Vaadin to appear on the left side without using FormLayout?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Is there a way to get the captions in Vaadin to appear on the left side **WITHOUT** using `FormLayout`? I bolded it because I'm trying to avoid this being the first answer. I understand that `FormLayout` offers this ability but in some cases I need to use something like `GridLayout` to be able to have two columns of data (for example firstname and lastname, start date and end date, and so on).

Comment: Also what's special about FormLayout that allows the caption to be on the left? Is it because the layout is very limited. And if so is this why they only offer a single column of data?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do it, because every layout generates appropriate space for components inside them. You can change easily order of caption and corresponding component inside "box" generated by a layout using simple CSS rules but its hard to dynamically determine the size of the box - thats what layouts do. I demonstrate it in the following image:
[image]

As you can see, I was able to swap order of a caption and its textfield using this CSS:

```
#your-id .v-caption {
  position: relative !important;
  top: 10px !important;
}

#your-id .your-component {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

and code

```
    GridLayout l = new GridLayout(2,2);
    l.addStyleName("your-id");
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        TextField qq = new TextField();
        qq.setCaption("DuDuDu");
        qq.addStyleName("your-component");
        l.addComponent(qq);
    }
```

*(I've applied these rules in Firefox CSS editor so only one slot has changed)*
This was possible only because I didin't have to change the size of `v-gridlayout-slot` . The size is dynamically generated by Vaadin and you can't tell Vaadin "generate me slot for my textfield and caption and I want caption on the left/right side".

Comment: Thanks, I think its a brilliant idea to add id to the style :) You just saved me 1-2 hours of work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GridLayout, you could create additional column for captions and manage its appearance manually.

[Vaadin Book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.features.html) says:

> An alternative way to implement a caption is to use another component as the caption, typically a Label, a TextField, or a Panel. A Label, for example, allows highlighting a shortcut key with HTML markup or to bind the caption to a data source. The Panel provides an easy way to add both a caption and a border around a component.

This approach gives you more flexibility. Therefore, it is worth remembering.